# How to access local and server database in a single project/file Randomly

Tags: php, mysql

How to access local and server database in a single project/file Randomly

The PHP code runs only if I'm connected to the internet through which I can access server database. And if I disable the internet I cannot access the local database.

Here's my code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'dbcon.php';
include_once 'dbcon1.php';

if(isset($_POST['save_mul']))
{       
$total = $_POST['total'];

for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
{
    $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
    $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];        
    $sql="INSERT INTO adairycf_gls.users (first_name,last_name)   VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."')";
    $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);        
}

if($sql == true)
{
    echo "sccess fully";
}

if ($sql == false) {
    $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
    $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];        
    $sql="INSERT INTO multi.users (first_name,last_name) VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."')";
    $sql = $MySQLiconn1->query($sql);   
}
}
?>`
```

Comment: Have you checked your local server, is it working or not ? `I mean is your Xampp or Wampp server` on

Comment: What do you mean with *in single php randomly*?

Comment: @lino I guess it means in a single file or project

Answer (score 0):

You can [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) a constant, like
define("DEVELOPMENT", true);

further in your script you can make a if else like:

```
if(DEVELOPMENT) {
    // connect to local
} else {
   // connect to online server
}
```

Edit:
You can even check the IP address from wich you are making a connection.
And put a if around the define, to check it on IP.
Thats how i handle it in my own projects

Comment: I had used 2 **dbconfig.php** files but a program default take a first one only how to define to access two of the **config.php files**

Comment: Why would you use 2 dbconfig.php? Just make a different connection depending on the environment.

You can use the if/else in my example.